# cumulative script calculation of depodit

Tags: javascript

A calculation that** returns 10% **of the deposit and *adds* the same  10% of the of the deposit *`every 24hr`* on the *initial* 10% after the deposit for 30 days , i obtained the 10% but i failed to add 10% on the initial 10%

```
<script>

new_deposit =  (deposit * 0.1)

function calculate() {
  // Get the current deposit amount from the form
  var deposit = document.getElementById("deposit").value;

  // Calculate the 10% increase
  var new_deposit =  (deposit * 0.1);

  // Update the display of the deposit amount
  document.getElementById("deposit_display").innerHTML = new_deposit;
}

// Run the calculate function every 24 hours (86400000 milliseconds)
setInterval(calculate, 86400000);




</script>
```

Comment: elevant HTML is missing on the question [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

use code:

```js
function calculate(money) {
  money += money * 0.1

  document.getElementById("deposit_display").innerHTML = money;

  setTimeout(() => calculate(money), 86400000);
}

setTimeout(() => calculate(document.getElementById("deposit").value), 86400000);
```